# Remove the duplicate values before pushing into an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

It's visible in the image that the array[0] and array[3], array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdYiZ.png) and array[4] are same. I was checking why the values are duplicating but I failed. So thought to just remove if any duplicate values exists. I need to remove it from 
$scope.arr array itself.

Code:

```
  $scope.arr = [];
planReq.then(function (callplanList) {
    $scope.callplanList = callplanList.data.callplans;
    //console.log($scope.callplanList);
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.planMapping.length; i++){
        //console.log($scope.planMapping[i].PlanScode);         
        for(var j = 0; j < $scope.callplanList.length; j++){                
            if(($scope.planMapping[i].PlanScode == $scope.callplanList[j].un_s_code) && ($scope.callplanList[j].offer_type == "REC")){
                //console.log($scope.devicesList);
                for(var a = 0; a < $scope.callplanList[j].upfront_cost.length; a++){
                    if($scope.callplanList[j].upfront_cost[a].upfront != ""){
                        //console.log($scope.callplanList[j].upfront_cost[a].handsetClass);
                        for(var k = 0; k < $scope.devicesList.length; k++){
                            if($scope.callplanList[j].upfront_cost[a].handsetClass == $scope.devicesList[k].device_class.toLowerCase()){
                                $scope.arr.push($scope.devicesList[k]);                                 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
    console.log($scope.arr);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use track by on ng-repeat

Comment: use track by index in ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of **filter**.

Here is a simple filter, to remove duplicates from an array

`Array.filter(function(elem, index, self){ return self.indexOf(elem) == index })`

In your case it will be

```
$scope.arr =  $scope.arr.filter(function(elem, index, self){ 
                                  return self.indexOf(elem) == index 
                                });
```

Comment: Should I add this code before $scope.arr.push($scope.devicesList[k]); this?

Comment: After your final array ready then put this line. Like this,

`$scope.arr.push($scope.devicesList[k]);`
`$scope.arr =  $scope.arr.filter(function(elem, index, self){ 
                                  return self.indexOf(elem) == index 
                                });`

Answer (score 0):

`method 1`:

```
var list =[{name:"a",age:2}, {name:"b",age:4}, {name:"c",age:6}, {name:"a",age:2}]
var arr = list.filter((elem, index, self) => self.findIndex(
    (t) => {return (t.name === elem.name && t.age === elem.age)}) === index)
```

it return unique array based on all the properties

`method 2`:

If you want to remove duplicate elements from an array use the following function. Here the args are:
myArr: contain array ob objects
prop: the property of object by which the array elements should be removed

```
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
  return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
  });
}
```

It will remove the duplicates based on the elements property and return the array with unique elemnts.

Comment: I want to remove from existing $scope.arr array itself

Comment: If all the property values are same.

Comment: try 1st method. instead of `list`, use your array

Answer (score 0):

ngRepeat uses $watchCollection to detect changes in the collection. When a change happens, ngRepeat then makes the corresponding changes to the DOM:

When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the DOM.
When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from the DOM.
When items are reordered, their respective templates are reordered in the DOM.
To minimize creation of DOM elements, ngRepeat uses a function to "keep track" of all items in the collection and their corresponding DOM elements. For example, if an item is added to the collection, ngRepeat will know that all other items already have DOM elements, and will not re-render them.

The default tracking function (which tracks items by their identity) does not allow duplicate items in arrays. This is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements.

If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.

so you can do like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
 {{n}}
 </div>
```

If you want to remove duplicates from array :

```
function UniqueArraybyId(collection, keyname) {
              var output = [], 
                  keys = [];

              angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
                  var key = item[keyname];
                  if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                      keys.push(key);
                      output.push(item);
                  }
              });
        return output;
   }; 
planReq.then(function (callplanList) {
    $scope.callplanList = callplanList.data.callplans;
    //console.log($scope.callplanList);
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.planMapping.length; i++){
        //console.log($scope.planMapping[i].PlanScode);         
        for(var j = 0; j < $scope.callplanList.length; j++){                
            if(($scope.planMapping[i].PlanScode == $scope.callplanList[j].un_s_code) && ($scope.callplanList[j].offer_type == "REC")){
                //console.log($scope.devicesList);
                for(var a = 0; a < $scope.callplanList[j].upfront_cost.length; a++){
                    if($scope.callplanList[j].upfront_cost[a].upfront != ""){
                        //console.log($scope.callplanList[j].upfront_cost[a].handsetClass);
                        for(var k = 0; k < $scope.devicesList.length; k++){
                            if($scope.callplanList[j].upfront_cost[a].handsetClass == $scope.devicesList[k].device_class.toLowerCase()){
                                $scope.arr.push($scope.devicesList[k]);                                 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

   $scope.arr = UniqueArraybyId($scope.arr ,"sub_family"); //you have to pass the key name 


    console.log($scope.arr);
})
```

Here is the fiddle :

```js
function UniqueArraybyId(collection, keyname) {
              var output = [], 
                  keys = [];

              angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
                  var key = item[keyname];
                  if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                      keys.push(key);
                      output.push(item);
                  }
              });
        return output;
   }; 
   
function test () {
    
    var arr =[{sub_family:'j3 (2016)'},{sub_family:'j3 (2016)'},{sub_family:'j3 (2017)'}]
     arr= UniqueArraybyId(arr ,"sub_family"); //you have to pass the key name 

    
    console.log(arr);
};

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to remove it from $scope.arr.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to remove duplicates from an Array. Note that this requires ES6.

```
arr = Array.from(new Set(arr));
```

Example:

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4];
console.log(arr.join(", "));
arr = Array.from(new Set(arr));
console.log(arr.join(", "));
```